# Typescript import functions into existing module's scope

Tags: javascript, typescript, module

Is there a way I can import a module(?) (a set of functions) in typescript and be able to refer to these functions without the `Module.` prefix?

For example:

```
import * as Operations from './Operations';
```

Can I reference `Operations.example()` as `example()`? Essentially merging the 'namespace'?

Comment: What about just importing example from `./Operations`? can you please show how `Operations` is? does it have a default export?

Comment: I am free to define the `Operations` file in any way. But essentially I want to define a set of functions that can be imported anywhere.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do:

```js
import { example } from './Operations';
```

This assumes you are exporting `example` from the file as a named export.

```js
// ./Operations
export function example () {...}
```

[Typescript Module Documentation](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/modules.html)

Comment: This requires I write out all the functions, is there way to specify all of the exported functions?

Comment: @ChrisStryczynski unfortunately no. If you have each as a named export you either need to specify each in a `{}` or use `import * as namespace`